# How can I search for elements within a polygon with Overpass?

Tags: matlab, coordinates, element, overpass-api

I am new to Overpass API and GIS in general.

Is there an easy way to export all buildings in a specific region using coordinates to specify the polygon? I couldn't find a solution using the wiki and google so far.

I have large sets of coordinates which are determining some medium-voltage grids.

Or is there another tool I could use? 
I want to use the polygon- coordinates of the exported buildings in matlab.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can use [overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) just search for building (assistant->building-> search)

Comment: yes. but this will find all buildings in the bbox or tagged city or region. I want to determine the area by using coordinates.

Comment: I guess you need to study the `(poly: )` filter in more detail, see [wiki link](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_polygon_.28poly.29)

Comment: I guess I know how to select the region by a Polygon. But I don't know how I can get the buildings inside this Polygon as single elements. 

`(
node(poly:"50.7 7.1 50.7 7.12 50.71 7.11");
node["building"](poly:"50.7 7.1 50.7 7.12 50.71 7.11");
  <;
);
out meta;`


This code gives me every single coordinate with the building tag but not the whole building. [wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Select_region_by_polygon) says I can use polygones only as borders for notes.

Comment: ... So my Question is how can I get the buildings as polygons?

Comment: Buildings are usually modeled as `way`, rather than `node`: --> `way[building](poly: xxxx); (._;>;);out meta;`

Comment: `runtime error: Query failed with the exception: std::bad_alloc`
I tried the simple polygon: `way[building](poly: "50.7 7.1 50.7 7.12 50.71 7.11"); (._;>;);out meta;`

I'm feeling so stupid - thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: This looks like a recent regression. You might want to try a different evaluation sequence instead: `way(poly: "50.7 7.1 50.7 7.12 50.71 7.11");way._[building];(._;>;);out meta;`

Comment: Thank you! This works well so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overpass API provides the `(poly: )` filter to query objects inside a given polygon. See the [documentation in the wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_polygon_.28poly.29) for details.

Buildings in a given polygon can be queried as follows:

```
way[building](poly:"50.7 7.1 50.7 7.12 50.71 7.11");
(._;>;);
out meta;
```

Due to a recent memory limitation, you might have to either add a `[maxsize: xxx]` setting:

```
[maxsize:2073741824];
way[building](poly:"50.7 7.1 50.7 7.12 50.71 7.11");
(._;>;);
out;
```

or resort to the following workaround to force another evaluation sequence:

```
way(poly: "50.7 7.1 50.7 7.12 50.71 7.11");
way._[building];
(._;>;);
out meta;
```